# How to change a period element (from lubridate package) to time with format "%H:%M:%S"?

Tags: r, time, character, lubridate

How could we change the period element "19H 43M 0S" to "19:43:00" (specifically "%H:%M:%S" format) in R?

Comment: use the `chron` library? `chron(times=gsub("[^ 0-9]","","19H 43M 0S"), format=c(times="h m s"))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sprintf` with get the `format`

```
library(lubridate)
sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour(v1), minute(v1), second(v1))
#[1] "19:43:00"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- period("19hours 43minutes")
```